# Assigning references from an array to another array - "warning: target of assignment not really an lvalue"

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

Consider the following code. I've included excessive couts for clarity (at least on my end):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
double *array1;    
array1 = new double[10];
array1[5] = 10;

//the following 2 lines return the same thing
cout << "array1 = " << array1 << endl;
cout << "&array1[0] = " << &array1[0] << endl;

double *subarray1;
subarray1 = new double[5];
subarray1 = &array1[5];

//now the following 2 lines return the same thing
cout << array1[5] << endl;
cout << subarray1[0] << endl;

//but I'm not allowed to do:
//&subarray1[0] = &array1[5];

return 0;
}
```

since

```
subarray1 == &subarray1[0]
```

and since I am allowed to do this:

```
subarray1 = &array1[5];
```

then why can't I do this:

```
&subarray1[0] = &array1[5];
```

The error that I receive is: warning: target of assignment not really an lvalue; this will be a hard error in the future

Comment: What on _earth_ are you trying to do?

Comment: You're trying to assign to the result of the address-of operator! Why would you expect that to work? (And what would it do?)

Comment: My original intent was to build a subarray whose elements point to different elements in array, i.e. subarray[0] == array[0], subarray[1] == array[4], without doing a hard copy.

Comment: @Tom: Why? Alias/map the indexes instead if you _really_ need something like this. Don't try to alias/map the elements themselves; you'll just get in a pickle.

Comment: Is there any other solution? I: a) don't want to make copies, because the arrays are huge, and b) don't want to always index the array because it doesn't look clean and makes my code more difficult to read. So, is there no other solution to make an equivalent of: subarray1 = &array1[5]; for non-consecutive array referencing?

Comment: Nobody said anything about making copies! I said to alias/map the indexes, which solves your problem `b)` outright.

Comment: Also note that `subarray1 = new double[5]; subarray1 = &array1[5]` leaks memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `subarray1` is an *lvalue* to your pointer object of the same name. This pointer points to the first element of the dynamically-allocated buffer.

The expression `&subarray1[0]` is an *rvalue* pointer that points to the first element of the dynamically-allocated buffer (and thus it evaluates to the same value as `subarray1`).

These are *not* the same thing, and you may not assign to an *rvalue*.

Comment: gotcha. So can I set the lvalue of different elements in subarray1?

Comment: Do you want subarray1 to be an array of pointers to double? Two different double objects cannot refer to the same storage, but you can make a pointer point wherever you want.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for your help - so what is happening when I set array1[5] = 5, array1[6] = 6, set subaray1 = &array1[5], and then subsequently have subarray1[0] = 5, subarray1[1] = 6 ?

Comment: subarray1[0] = 5 sets array1[5] to 5 and subarray1[1] = 6 sets array1[6] to 6, so the previously set values in array1 stay the same. so in this case, subarray1 is a subarray of array1 starting at index 5.